# How should I create classes in ATL project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, com, atl

I'm writing an ATL project and I wonder how should I create classes here.
Right now I have one class created by *Add/Class/ATL Simple Object*. I want to divide it to smaller classes but method from this classes should use `CComPtr` and have `CComPtr` as an argument. I can't create 'simple' c++ class because I don't have `CComPtr` there.

Should I create ATL classes by *ATL Simple Object Wizard* and then use interface for this class to call methods. Like here:

```
CComPtr<ITestAtlClass> tptr;
tptr.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TestAtlClass);
tptr->test();
```

And should I add all public methods by *Class View/ITestAtlClass/Add/Add Method*?
What about constructors? Do I must initialize my class only by properties (and add them by *Class View/ITestAtlClass/Add/Add Property*)? And pass every com object by IUnknown interface?

Can somebody tell me how it should be done in ATL project. I will use this smaller classes internally (nobody will create this classes outside my DLL) just to make my code more readable.

Comment: Only create ATL classes for interfaces that should be visible outside the DLL.

Comment: @Hans Passant
But I can't create simple c++ class that is using CComPtr for example.
How to use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't understand your comment that you can't use `CComPtr` from a simple C++ class. Can you please clarify?

I see two strategies:

- build a clean C++ object model that solves the problem, and then wrap it in a thin facade layer of one or more COM objects
- Use ATL classes throughout, and use `CComObject<>` and derivatives to instantiate and maintain these without the overhead of `CoCreateInstance` and the limitations of only using public interfaces.

The first one is usually much nicer, but if you're building a data-heavy object model, the second can be a useful technique.

If you have an ATL COM class called `CVehicle`, that derives from `CComObjectRootEx<>` and friends, you can instantiate it like so;

```
   CComObject<CVehicle>* vehicle = NULL;
   CComObject<CVehicle>::CreateInstance(&vehicle);

   vehicle->AddRef();

   // To get at any of its interfaces, use:
   CComPtr<ICar> car = 0;
   vehicle->QueryInterface(&car);

   // And to delete object, use:
   vehicle->Release();
```

There's also variations on `CComObject<>`, e.g. `CComObjectStack<>` that use different allocation and reference counting strategies.

As you can see, this is pretty messy. If you can explain what you mean by your comment on not being able to use `CComPtr`, maybe I can expand on that.

Comment: Thank You very much!! It looks that I just don't understand how to use these ATL classes. Now when you showed me this sample I found the same on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e31say1.aspx).


Can I create ATL classes like that too?: 
`CComObject<CVehicle> vehicle; vehicle.someMethod()` Then I won't have to worry about releasing memory?

Or can I write something like this:
`CComPtr<CComObject<CVehicle>>; CComObject<CVehicle>::CreateInstance(&vehicle);` And the it will Release itself when unneeded?

Comment: When I said I can't use CComPtr I didn't know to to create ALT object... I tried including `atlcomcli.h` and `atlcom.h` to normal c++ class (crated without ATL Simple Object Wizard).

I'm a little ashamed but these ATL resources aren't great.

Comment: In order to create objects on the stack, as you show, you use `CComObjectStack<>`. I'm not sure if a CComObjectStack can be embedded inside another class as a member variable, you may want to read up on the other CComObject variations.

Comment: No, ATL has always been under-documented. I never bothered to keep up with MSDN after I found the book ATL Internals -- it covers this stuff in perfect detail: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321159624/

Comment: `CComPtr` is in atlcomcli.h, though it's probably in namespace ATL by default, so you may need to use `ATL::CComPtr` to get at it. Usually you include ATL in your precompiled header (stdafx.h), so it's available to all headers and .cpp files in your project. Maybe the namespace qualification is what's tripping you up?

Comment: Thanks again. Of course this was a problem with ATL namespace. Now I have normal C++ class that use `CComPtr` and `CComQIPtr` without any problems.

Comment: CComPtr<> is old, use at least _COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IUserIcePiece, __uuidof(IUserIcePiece)) instead and you wount need to use CComPtr::p sometimes.

Comment: @IgriZdes: I don't think that's a fair characterization. They are just different libraries with different tradeoffs. _COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF is part of the Compiler COM Support classes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h31ekh7e.aspx) and CComPtr is part of ATL. Last I did Windows development (and it's been a few years), ATL was still being improved and the _com_ptr_t classes were at a relative standstill.